# SQL: Additional condition inside the 'like'-condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, sql-like

here's my query:

```
    SELECT
      p1.time_neu as Datum
      count(p1.*) as Anzahl_Palette,
      count(p2.*) as Anzahl_Stangen_Behaelter
    FROM
      00_Gesamt_Pickauf p1,
      00_Gesamt_Pickauf p2
    WHERE
      p1.platz_von like '%-%-00-00' AND
      p2.platz_von like ...
```

I've got trouble with the second like-condition. I want to select all the rows, where the "platz_von"-coloumn looks like this:

```
    01-01-01-01
    02-02-02-02
    02-02-03-04
    ...
```

But not like this:

```
    01-02-00-00
    02-01-00-00
```

I need to filter all the rows where "platz_von" does not end on "-00-00". Any hints on how to write the query? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
  SELECT
      p1.time_neu as Datum
      count(p1.*) as Anzahl_Palette,
      count(p2.*) as Anzahl_Stangen_Behaelter
    FROM
      00_Gesamt_Pickauf p1,
      00_Gesamt_Pickauf p2
    WHERE
      p1.platz_von NOT LIKE '%-00-00%' AND
      p2.platz_von like ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  p1.time_neu AS Datum
  count(p1.*) AS Anzahl_Palette,
  count(p2.*) AS Anzahl_Stangen_Behaelter
FROM
  00_Gesamt_Pickauf p1,
  00_Gesamt_Pickauf p2
WHERE
  p1.platz_von like '%-%-%-%' AND
  NOT (p1.platz_von like '%-%-00-00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add NOT and change '%-%-00-00' to '%-00-00' since you only want exclude that end with 00-00

```
SELECT
  p1.time_neu as Datum
  count(p1.*) as Anzahl_Palette,
  count(p2.*) as Anzahl_Stangen_Behaelter
FROM
  00_Gesamt_Pickauf p1,
  00_Gesamt_Pickauf p2
WHERE
  p1.platz_von NOT LIKE'%-00-00' AND
  p2.platz_von LIKE ...
```